# QGIS Rasterize - Use highest value in cell as burn in value

Tags: qgis, rasterization, gdal-rasterize

I am trying to create raster layers of presence/absence bridges in a project area to use as inputs for habitat suitability models. I am using 15 m x 15 m cell size.

The presence of bridges is represented by 6 m diameter circular polygons following conversion of point data to polygon through buffering). The polygons are coded 1 = presence of bridge, and 0 = absence.

When I create the raster, not all of the bridge locations show up (value 0 returned where I want 1). I assume this because the value that covers the majority of the raster cell is being burned in, which in may cases would be 0 - absence.

I want all cells that contain a bridge to return a value of 1, regardless of the total area of the cell that is covered by the bridge polygon.

How would I specify that the maximum value from the cell be used as the burn in value or what are other ways I could achieve this goal?

I am using QGIS 3.4 primarially but also have 3.10

Comment: Hi Erica. The _Rasterize_ tool takes the value where the center of the pixel is located (that is what I think, not totally sure) instead of the cell most covered value. Maybe a workaround is creating a rectangular polygons vector grid, representing the borders of the cells, assigning to those polygons a value of `1` if they intersects a value of `1` buffered polygon, and then rasterizing the grid. Seems a bit complicated, but do you know exactly the position and spatial resolution of the pixels?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I was able to achieve the goal using the SAGA Rasterize tool, specifying 'Method for multiple values' as 'maximum'.

Comment: Good to know it, can you write an answer about how do you solve it?